# String Array in c++

Tags: c++

```
Output is not correct.Every line miss its first character
```

Now When i enter size of array and then entered value of each index.Output will not properly shown, at 2nd,3rd and 4th line of output first character of input is missing

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Enter the size of array :";
    cin>>size;
     string name[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Enter string at "<<i<<" index of array :";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin,name[i]);

    }
    //out put of array
    cout<<"OutPut of array "<<endl;
    for(int i=0 ; i<size ;i++)
    {
        cout<<name[i]<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: This isn't valid C++. Array sizes must be constant expressions.

Comment: `string name[size];`  This is not standard C++.  Instead use `std::vector<string> name(size);`

Answer (score 1):

Take cin.ignore() out of the loop. This way:

```
cin.ignore();
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    cout<<endl<<"Enter string at "<<i<<" index of array :";

    getline(cin,name[i]);

}
```

Earlier, cin.ignore() was executed every time in the loop, and forced ignoring every first character of string. The modified code: http://ideone.com/5S1yVv